# error : constant expression required

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to open a new activity when I click on one of the name of the "string", for example, click on "pila 12v" and open new activity, in this case open "Main5Activity".

When placing the "case values [0]" a message appears:constant expression required.

```
    package com.example.epson.mp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


AutoCompleteTextView values;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String[] values = new String[]{"bateria 9v", "pila 9v", "bateria 12v", "pila 12v"};
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,values);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMercancias);
        textView.setThreshold(3);//will start working from third character
        textView.setAdapter(adapter); //setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
        textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
                //This will give you the string value of selected list item
                TextView listItem = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);
                //You can do this or apply own logic to find the selected value case
                switch (listItem.getText().toString()){
                    case values[0]:
                        Intent myintent0 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myintent0, 0);
                        break;
                    case values[1]:
                        Intent myintent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myintent1, 1);
                        break;
                    case values[2]:
                        Intent myintent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main4Activity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myintent2, 2);
                        break;
                    case values[3]:
                        Intent myintent3 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main5Activity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myintent3, 3);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: You cannreplace the case with if...else structure

Comment: It's telling you that you need a constant expression. `value[0]` isn't a constant expression -- it depends on the contents of that `value` array. So you can't use `switch`, and have to use something else (like an if-else-if chain, or a `Map<String,Runnable>` of actions, or an enum).

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to do that. Could you help me? please